# Can we use CSS in a Silverlight project

Tags: silverlight

I have a problem. I want to make a web application using silver light. I just want to know that can I use a css in this, because I read the the designing of silver light is in the xaml or we use css with html tag.

Is anybody clear my confusion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Silverlight XAML ≠ HTML+CSS

These are all different technologies. You probably better know Adobe Flash. Well Silverlight is very similar. It (may) run in the context of a browser, but it has nothing to do with HTML and/or CSS. It uses XAML files (as you pronounce them *zammel*). So if you decide to write a Silverlight application you will have to use XAML files and use Expression Blend to design your UI. Doing so would be faster than hand editing XAML files.

Answer (score 0):

xaml is like html + css but its not the same , they have some things in common but nothing much important .
Better find yourself good video tutorials or a book and learn it from there :)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't really use CSS in a silverlight project.

If it's worth the effort, what you could do is manually load the required CSS files with the `WebClient` class and parse them to style your controls accordingly.

Someone did something similar with the Sharepoint theme files, which are yet another format. [Using SharePoint thmx files to style Silverlight](http://chris.59north.com/post/Using-SharePoint-thmx-files-to-style-Silverlight.aspx) describes how to do it. Maybe you can find some inspiration from that.